# How to change a 'date' in Char format to date format in teradata SQL?

Tags: sql, date, teradata

I have a column date like
`date CHAR(7) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,` where i have some values like 2010-12, 2011-10, etc. i want to change these into the date format yyyy/mm . How do i do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Simply apply a FORMAT dring the CAST:

```
SELECT CAST('2010-12' AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYY/MM')
```

This returns a valid date with the day set to the 1st of this month.